# Magento 2 Import Order Programetically

Tags: magento2

I am trying to import order from XML file and i am gettging bellow error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCountryId() on null in vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php:614
Stack trace:
#0 generated/code/Magento/OfflinePayments/Model/Cashondelivery/Interceptor.php(362): Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod->validate()
#1 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(353): Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery\Interceptor->validate()
#2 generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment/Interceptor.php(167): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->place()
#3 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php(873): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor->place()
#4 vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php(1080): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->_placePayment()
#5 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->place()
#6 vendor/magento/framework in vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php on line 614
```

My code is here

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Import\Console;


use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface;
use Prewk\XmlStringStreamer;
use Prewk\XmlStringStreamer\Stream;
use Prewk\XmlStringStreamer\Parser;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;

class Ordersimprove extends Command
{
    protected $helper;
    protected $directoryList;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $file;
    protected $product;
    protected $cartRepositoryInterface;
    protected $cartManagementInterface;
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $order;
    protected $transaction;
    protected $invoice_service;
    protected $shippingRate;
    protected $website_id;
    protected $eavConfig;
    protected $address;
    protected $payment;
    protected $item;
    protected $saveTransaction;
    public function __construct(
        \PySoft\Import\Helper\Data $helper,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        DirectoryList $directoryList,
        File $file,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $product,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $OrderFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $Order,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoice_service,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $transaction,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $shippingRate,
        EavConfig $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface $address,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface $payment,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $item,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore('admin');
        $this->website_id=1;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
        $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->OrderFactory = $OrderFactory;
        $this->order = $Order;
        $this->invoice_service=$invoice_service;
        $this->transaction=$transaction;
        $this->shippingRate = $shippingRate;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->address=$address;
        $this->payment=$payment;
        $this->item=$item;
        $this->saveTransaction = $transactionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('initialimport:ordersimprove');
        $this->setDescription('Import orders from summer cart');
        parent::configure();
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
        $dir = $this->directoryList->getPath('var');
        $Orders = $dir . "/initialimport/Orders.xml";
        $streamer = XmlStringStreamer::createUniqueNodeParser($Orders, array("uniqueNode" => "Order"));
        $count = 0;
        while ($node = $streamer->getNode()) {
            $count++;
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($node, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
            $order=$xml;//json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
            $this->processOrder($order,$output);
        }
        $output->writeln("Orders Imported");
    }
    private function processOrder($order,$output){
        if($this->isOrderExit($order->OrderID)){
            $this->createOrdersimprove($order,$output);
        }else{
            $this->helper->log("Order with #{$order->OrderID} Skip");
            $output->writeln("Order with #{$order->OrderID} Skip");
        }
    }
    private function generateCustomerEmail($orderData){
        /** Ans: create a md5 hash from the name md5hash@test.bg email sonwe dont loose the ordering. (Guest Order) **/
        $name='';
        if(!empty($orderData->OrderBillingFirstName)){
            $name=$orderData->OrderBillingFirstName;
        }
        if(!empty($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingFirstName))){
            $name.=' '.$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingLastName);
        }
        if(empty($name)){
            $name=$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingFirstName);
            $name.=' '.$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingLastName);
        }
        $email=md5($name)."@test.bg";
        return $email;
    }
    private function getFormatShippingAddress($orderData,$customer=''){
        $address=array();
        $street='';
        if($orderData->OrderShippingAddress1){
            $street=$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingAddress1);
        }
        if($orderData->OrderShippingAddress2) {
            $street .= " ".$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingAddress2);
        }
        $address=$this->address->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->setAddressType('shipping')
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setFirstname($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingFirstName))
            ->setLastname($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingLastName))
            ->setStreet($this->getTextDefaultValue($street))
            ->setCity($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingCity))
            ->setCountryId($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingCountryCode2,'country'))
            ->setRegion($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingState))
            ->setPostcode($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingZip,'postcode'))
            ->setTelephone($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingPhone,'telephone'))
            ->setVatId($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingVatNumber))
            ->setFax($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingFax));

        return $address;
    }
    private function getFormatBillingAddress($orderData,$customer=''){
        $address=array();
        $street='';
        if($orderData->OrderShippingAddress1){
            $street=$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingAddress1);
        }
        if($orderData->OrderShippingAddress2) {
            $street .= " ".$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShippingAddress2);
        }
        $address=$this->address->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->setAddressType('billing')
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setFirstname($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingFirstName))
            ->setLastname($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingLastName))
            ->setCompany($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingCompany))
            ->setStreet($this->getTextDefaultValue($street))
            ->setCity($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingCity))
            ->setCountryId($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingCountryCode2,'country'))
            ->setRegion($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingState))
            ->setPostcode($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingZip))
            ->setTelephone($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingPhone))
            ->setVatId($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingVatNumber))
            ->setFax($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingFax))
            ->setBillingTaxNumber($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingTaxNumber))
            ->setTaxOffice($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingTaxOffice))
            ->setPersonalNumber($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingPersonalNumber))
            ->setInvoiceContactPerson($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingPersonalNumber))
            ->setIsCompany($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingIsCompany))
            ->setBankName($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingIsCompany))
            ->setBankAccount($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingIsCompany));
        return $address;
    }
    private function createOrdersimprove($orderData,$output) {
        $output->writeln("Order Created Start :".$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderID));
        $store=$this->storeManager->getStore();
        $order=$this->OrderFactory->create();
        $customer='';
        $increment_id = $this->eavConfig->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($store->getId());

        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $email=(string)$orderData->OrderCustomerEmail;
        $is_guest_order=false;
        if (empty(trim($email))) {
            $is_guest_order=true;
            $email=$this->generateCustomerEmail($orderData);
            if(empty($email)){
                $this->helper->log("Order #".$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderID).' Invalid email ');
                $output->writeln("Order # ".$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderID).' invalid email=>'.$orderData->OrderCustomerEmail);
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(!$is_guest_order){
            $customer=$this->customerRepository->get($email);
            if(!$customer->getId() && !$is_guest_order){
                $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
                $customer->setWebsiteId($this->website_id)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingFirstName))
                    ->setLastname($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderBillingLastName))
                    ->setEmail($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderCustomerEmail));
                $customer->save();
            }
            $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getId());
        }
        $order->setIncrementId($increment_id)
            ->setStoreId($store->getId())
            ->setQuoteId(0)
            ->setGlobalCurrencyCode('BGN')
            ->setOrderCurrencyCode('BGN')
            ->setBaseCurrencyCode('BGN')
            ->setStoreCurrencyCode('BGN')
            ->setCustomerEmail($customer->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
            ->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
            ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(0)
            ->setCustomer($customer);

        $subTotal = 0;
        foreach ($orderData->OrderItems->OrderItem as $OrderItem) {
            $product = $this->product->get('navin');
            $product->setPrice($OrderItem->OrderItemPrice);
            $rowTotal = $product->getPrice() * intval($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemQty));
            $orderItem = $this->item
                ->setStoreId($store->getId())
                ->setQuoteItemId(0)
                ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
                ->setProductId($product->getId())
                ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
                ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
                ->setTotalQtyOrdered(intval($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemQty)))
                ->setQtyOrdered(intval($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemQty)))
                ->setName($product->getName())
                ->setSku($product->getSku())
                ->setPrice($product->getPrice())
                ->setBasePrice($product->getPrice())
                ->setOriginalPrice($product->getPrice())
                ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
                ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)
                ->setDistributorPrice($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemDistributorPrice))
                ->setBonusPointsSpent($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemBonusPointsSpent))
                ->setOriginalProductCode($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemOriginalProductCode))
                ->setProductWasPrice($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemProductWasPrice))
                ->setIsPromoBundle($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemProductIsPromoBundle))
                ->setBarcodes($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->OrderItemBarcodes))
                ->setEgoods($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->Egoods))
                ->setLocalOptions($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->LocalOptions))
                ->setGlobalOptions($this->getTextDefaultValue($OrderItem->GlobalOptions));
            $subTotal += $rowTotal;
            $order->addItem($orderItem);
        }
        $shipping_address=$this->getFormatShippingAddress($orderData,$customer);
        $billing_address=$this->getFormatBillingAddress($orderData,$customer);
        $order->setSubtotal($subTotal)->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)->setGrandTotal($subTotal)->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);
        $order->setBillingAddress($billing_address);
        $order->setShippingAddress($shipping_address);
        $order->setShippingMethod('extensaspeedy');
        $order->setShippingDescription('extensaspeedy');
        $order_payment = $this->payment->setMethod('cashondelivery');
        $order->setPayment($order_payment);
        $order->setOldOrderId($orderData->OrderID);
        $order->setEmailSent(0);
        $order->setComment($this->getOrderComment($orderData));
        $order->setUseLoyaltyCard($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->UseLoyaltyCard));
        $order->setCustomerCardNumber($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->CustomerCardNumber));
        $order->setShipToBillingAddress($this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderShipToBillingAddress));
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment($this->getOrderComment($orderData))->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
        $order_state_status=$this->getStateStatusCode($orderData);
        if(!empty($order_state_status)) {
            $order->setState($order_state_status['state'])->setStatus($order_state_status['status']);
        }
        $this->saveTransaction->addObject($order);
        $this->saveTransaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
        $this->saveTransaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
        $this->saveTransaction->save();
        $output->writeln("Order Created :".$this->getTextDefaultValue($orderData->OrderID));
    }

    private function isOrderExit($order_id){
        $order=$this->order->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('old_order_id',array('eq'=>$order_id));
        $order=$order->getFirstItem();
        if($order->getId()){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

any one have idea how to import oders in magento programtically without usage of Quote? what mistake in my code

Comment: can you check whether the country code is properly fetched from xml file and assigned to billing address & shipping address object.

Comment: yes that propery featch and assign i cross check many time